# How do I sort array of pairs based on the greater value in first or second

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, custom-function

```
bool custome_compare(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2){
    if (p1.first > p1.second || p1.second > p1.first) return true;
    else return false;
}
int main()
{
    pair<int, int> arr[4];
    arr[0].first = 4, arr[0].second = 10;
    arr[1].first = 7, arr[1].second = 6;
    arr[2].first = 3, arr[2].second = 8;
    arr[3].first = 9, arr[3].second = 1;

    sort(arr, arr + 4 , custome_compare);
    //---------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

My goal to sort the array of pairs based on the greater value.
I don't care the greater value is the first or the second element in the pair.

For example i have this pairs:

4,10
7,6
3,8
9,1

After sort them :

4,10
9,1
3,8
7,6

> So i'm not sorting based on first or second i sorting based on both.

How can I edit this compare function to do this task ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to compare the max of the two pairs.

```
bool custom_compare(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2){
    return std::max(p1.first, p1.second) < std::max(p2.first, p2.second); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
bool custome_compare(const std::pair<int, int> &p1, const std::pair<int, int> &p2)
{
    return std::max( p1.first, p1.second ) > std::max( p2.first, p2.second );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool custome_compare(const std::pair<int, int> &p1, const std::pair<int, int> &p2)
{
    return std::max( p1.first, p1.second ) > std::max( p2.first, p2.second );
}

int main() 
{
    std::pair<int, int> arr[] = 
    {
        { 4, 10 }, { 7, 6 }, { 3, 8 }, { 9, 1 }
    };


    for ( const auto &p : arr )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), custome_compare );

    for ( const auto &p : arr )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
4, 10
7, 6
3, 8
9, 1

4, 10
9, 1
3, 8
7, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The custom compare function should compare the max value of the pair(s). So something like:

```
bool custom_compare(pair<int, int> i, pair<int, int> j) { return max(i.first, 
i.second) > max(j.first, j.second); }
```

Not tested, nor tried to compile, but I hope you can work things out from here.

Comment: Just as colopop answered while I was typing my answer :-)

And with a better version, using the const & references.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on x86 CPU, you can use [x86-simd-sort](https://github.com/intel/x86-simd-sort?tab=readme-ov-file#sort-an-array-of-custom-defined-class-objects-uses-on-space), to sort arrays of C++ objects. It requires a lambda function that computes the key value for each object which is the metric used to sort them. In your case, you could call it like this:

```
x86simdsort::object_qsort(arr, arrsize, [](std::pair<int, int> elem) { return std::max(elem.first, elem.second); })
```